# How Do I Prevent Git Bash Highlight On Paste?

Tags: conemu, git-bash

When I use my mouse to copy text in Git Bash it highlights the text which is fine.

However, when I use the mouse to paste the text it also highlights the pasted text.

Now here comes the interesting part, when I ssh to a linux server and do the same thing, the pasted text is not highlighted!

How do I prevent it from highlighting the pasted text when using it in Windows?